# unable to get banner to scroll down

Tags: javascript, css

My Banner will not move down as the user scrolls down, and my button in the upper left of my image will not remove my image.

My banner will move down while the user scrolls down, but that is without the button in the upper left corner.

```js
document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", closeImage, false);

function closeImage() {
  var d = document.getElementById("wall");
  var d_nest = document.getElementById("image");
  var taway = d.removeChild(d_nest);
}
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    
    }
    .container img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     }
    .container .btn {
     position: absolute;
       top: 5%;
       left: 85%;
    .sticky {
    position: fixed;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="neptune.jpg" alt="Snow">
  <button class="btn" id="click">Button</button>

  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Stuck in a rut, main goal is to figure out how my banner can scroll down with my button in the image, and to figure out how to exit the banner once the button is clicked.

Comment: Hi, could you please also post the relevant css and javascript and explain specifically what the problem is with them?

Comment: Are you using display: sticky?
If so you need to define either a top, left, right, or bottom position

Comment: here is css code,, banner will not move down when i move the scroll bar

Comment: .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    
    }
    .container img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     }
    .container .btn {
     position: absolute;
       top: 5%;
       left: 85%;
    .sticky {
    position: fixed;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
   }

Comment: I am using .sticky  ..  my image is able to move down with the scroll bar, but when I add a button in the upper left, my image will not move

Comment: do not call that cariable throw:-)

Comment: The full html and CSS are required mate, please post them

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name a variable throw, you will get the exception "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw". Throw is a reserved key word for throwing exceptions.

```js
var throw = '';
```